# Struggling to print multiple MySQL rows to a web page using Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Trying to build a simple web app using Node.js. One of the pages requires multiple rows from one of my SQL table columns to be printed out like so:

*Here is the most recently added string from column X*

*Here is the second most recently added string*

*Here is the third*

*Here is the fourth*

*Here is the fifth*

I've got the hang of printing the first row using something like this:

```
 var q = 'SELECT mycolumn AS string FROM users';
 connection.query(q, function (error, results) {
 if (error) throw error; 
 var string = results[0].string;
 res.render('thanks', {string: string});
 });
});
```

However, I can't figure out how to print the results from rows 1-5. Closest I've got from Google is:

```
 connection.query('SELECT mycolumn AS string FROM users LIMIT 5', function (error, results) {
 if (error) throw error; 
 var string = JSON.stringify(results);
 res.render('thanks', {string: string});
 });
});
```

but this gives me `[{"mycolumn":"The content I'm trying to isolate"},{.....etc ]` as the output and I can't figure out a way to clean that up.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by specifying `results[0]` you are only getting the record with the index of 0 - which should be the first one.

Here is a sample of select query in one of my apps:

```
app.get('/categories', async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const allCategories = await pool.query("SELECT id, title FROM categories WHERE visible=true ORDER BY id desc");
    res.json(allCategories.rows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
});
```

You can see I don't have the `[0]` on my `rows` result.

Comment: Hi Sam. Thanks - I know I need to get rid of `results[0]` - I'm just not sure how to replace it so it has an output like `results[0 to 5]` (i.e. showing 5 rows).  If I just delete the "[0]" it comes through as an object. I can then stringify the object - see my second bit of code - but I get bad formatting. How I should modify the line `var string = results[0].string;` to solve for this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

````
 connection.query(q, function (error, results) {
 if (error) throw error; 
 var string1 = results[0].string;
 var string2 = results[1].string;
 var string3 = results[2].string;

 res.render('thanks', {string1: string1, string2: string2, string3: string3});
 });
});```
````